# MaterializeCSS 1.0.-rc.2 Dropdown without jQuery. How to hook onClick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

The idea is next:

There are two dropdown lists, which populated dynamically, first one only once, when the page is loaded, but second dropdown list should be populated dynamically every time when first list is clicked, and its content depends on selected item in the first list and I use jQuery to populate dropdown lists dynamically.

All content on the entire page wrapped on several tabs and contains the TinyMCE Editor. I tried to use jQuery with different versions of MaterializeCSS, but I met different issues (broken layout or "not clickable / dropping down" lists).

Using M instance without jQuery fixed all previous issues but I didn't find documentation on how to handle the `onClick` event with it and how to initialize again the dynamically updated dropdown lists?

HTML:

```
<!-- In head: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css"> -->
<!-- First Dropdown list -->
<div class="col s4 m2">
  <div class="nav-wrapper mar-top-20">
    <!-- https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html -->
    <!--Dropdown Trigger -->
    <a id="rec-years-trigger" class="dropdown-trigger waves-effect waves-light btn w100 avio" href="#" data-target="dropdown1">
      <?=data.currentMonth ?> <i class="medium material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
    </a>
    <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
    <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Second Dropdown list -->
<div class="col s6 m8">
  <div class="nav-wrapper mar-top-20">
    <!-- https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html -->
    <!--Dropdown Trigger -->
    <a id="post-list-trigger" class="dropdown-trigger waves-effect waves-light btn w100 avio" href="#" data-target="dropdown2">
      Posts<i class="medium material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
    </a>
    <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
    <ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content icons"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
...

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //generate a list:
  for (var i = 0; i < recYears.length; i++) {
    var newValue = recYears[i];
    var el = '<li><a href="#!" class="dropdown-button">' + newValue + '</a></li>';
    $("#dropdown1").append(el);
  };

  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
  var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, {
    belowOrigin: true
  });
  //Somewhere here OnClick EventHandler to populate second Dropdown list dynamically...
});
```